# Cannot log in through terminal services client

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-terminal-services

I have a windows 2008 R2 server within a FOO domain in my company. All user accounts are a part of BAR domain. FOO domain has full access to all objects (users and groups) in BAR domain.

Here's the problem: I have my own account and another user's added to the local administrator group on that server. We both are added to the Remote Desktop Users group as well. I can log in fine using the terminal services client, however the other user gets this error:

[image]

I tried adding his account directly in group policy (Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Management > Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services) and also added him to the roles under the Security tab of the RDP-Tcp settings, but that didn't solve my issue.

Any ideas? I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Check for explicit Deny permission entries that might apply to the other user.

Comment: @HopelessN00b where can I check that?